# push bulk of values to firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist

I want to store list of app details(name,package name,icon) already installed in my phone, already i displayed the list of installed app in list view using adapter. but won't able push the list of data into Firebase. anyone can tell me how to PUSH and RETRIEVE the list of data from firebase.

This is the code for code display a list app installed in mobile

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView apkList;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mFireBaseReference;

ArrayList<AppLIst> arrayList;

private ArrayList<String> _listActivitiesHidden = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<AppLIst> _listActivitiesAll = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<AppLIst> _customApp = new ArrayList();
private String appId;

PackageManager packageManager;
AppAdapter myAdapter;

private static  String userId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  mFireBaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("apps");
    packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
            .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

    List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

    /*To filter out System apps*/
    for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
        boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
        if(!b) {
            packageList1.add(pi);
        }
    }
    apkList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idListView);
     myAdapter = new AppAdapter(this,packageList,packageManager);
    apkList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

  //  apkList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
    return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
            : false;
}
```

I don't have any idea for store this list of data into firebase.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> `public Task<Void> setValue (Object value)`
>
> Set the data at this location to the given value. Passing null to `setValue()` will delete the data at the specified location. The native types accepted by this method for the value corresponding to the JSON types:
>
> ```
> Boolean
> Long
> Double
> String
> Map<String, Object>
> List<Object>
> ```

Therefore to add you can do the following:

```
mFireBaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("apps");
mFireBaseReference.setValue(packageList1);
```

Comment: i'm not able to understand where i'm gonna add this method 'public Task<void> setValue(object value)........ can u please explained or post some more lines code .

Comment: add it after `for(PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
        boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
        if(!b) {
            packageList1.add(pi);
        }
    }`

Comment: setValue will add data to the database.

Comment: Did the answer help you?